# Vue files dont show intellisense with javascript methods

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, jsdoc

I am running Vue 2.6 and using VSCode and my intellisense works just fine within js files, but once I try to use the intellisense from within a vue file, I lose all my intellisense.

I have the latest VSCode install and Vetur installed for working with Vue files.

index.js - This is an npm package of mine that i am importing into my Vue app.

```
class MyClass {
  /**
   * 
   * @param {string} str - ID of the DOM node to attach to.
   * @param {boolean|Object} opt - Other options stuff here....
   */
  constructor(str, opt) {}
}

export default MyClass;

new MyClass('abc', {}); <------ intellisense works here.
```

Page.vue

```
<!--- all vue template code here -->

<script>
  import MyClass from 'my-npm-package'; // This is the index.js file from my npm package.

  new MyClass(); <--------------- intellisense doesnt work here ever..

  export default {
    mounted() {
      new MyClass(); <--------------- intellisense doesnt work here either.. 
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: You shouldnt write Vue components like this, try looking at mixins if you want to put your javascript in a different file

Comment: The index.js file im accessing is an npm package of mine that gets imported into my Vue application

Answer (score 0):

You need plugin for VS Code to recognize Vue syntax

For Vue versions 2.x plugin is [Vetur](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=octref.vetur)

For Vue versions 3.x plugin is [Vue Language Features (Volar)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Vue.volar)

Comment: Volar is the official recommended one tbh.

Comment: I use Vetur currently but it still doesnt work for me. I also cant get any intellisense on methods from within the class either. Frustrating

Comment: @user616 did you selected Vue as a language aka `>Change Language Mode`?

Comment: In vscode? I didnt change any language modes. Default install

Comment: @user616 you can set what is the used language for a specific file. Try looking for what I posted above with your palette (`ctrl + shift + p` or alike).

Comment: I changed it to Vue and same result.

Comment: @user616 mind sharing a detailed video on what you're doing here?

Comment: Ok, so for whatever reason it seems to be working now.....not sure what i did but it seems to work now. Thanks

Comment: @user616 what fixed it? Toggling to Vue and restarting VScode?